# Slowing down numpy code with cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to accelerate an algorithm I have with cython. I've followed most of the proscriptions on [this page](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html) to take my original function and convert it into an optimized form, but all I appear to have done is slowed things down. I've checked the types pretty thoroughly, even looking into the generated C code, and I've done some line profiling as well that suggests that a lot of time is spent just comparing LONG types, but aside from that I haven't had any luck. I've noted inline the loop that seems to be the most expensive.

Am I just running into some very tight edge case? I find it hard to believe that cython wouldn't be able to optimize this code, so I assume that somewhere something is getting typed wrong.

My testing directory looks like this

```
cython_test
  - test_package
    - cython_fail
      - __init__.py
      - test_extension.pyx
    - setup.py
  - profiling.py
```

And the individual files looks like this:

### Init script

```
#__init__.py
__all__ = []
__version__ = 0.1
from . import test_extension
```

### Core code

```
# test_extension.pyx
import numpy as np

def fun(lattice, default_val = -1, leave_bar = True):
    if len(lattice.shape) != 2 or not np.all(
        np.logical_or(lattice == 0, lattice == 1)):
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Function only defined for 2D binary grid!")

    clusters = default_val*np.ones_like(lattice, dtype = DTYPE)
    ids = np.reshape(
        np.arange(
            1, lattice.shape[0]*lattice.shape[1] + 1
        ),
        lattice.shape)

    for i in range(lattice.shape[0]):
        for j in range(lattice.shape[1]):
            if lattice[i, j]:
                left_occ = lattice[i-1, j] if i != 0 else 0
                up_occ = lattice[i, j-1] if j != 0 else 0

                if not left_occ and not up_occ:
                    clusters[i, j] = ids[i, j]
                elif left_occ and not up_occ:
                    clusters[i, j] = clusters[i-1, j]
                elif not left_occ and up_occ:
                    clusters[i, j] = clusters[i, j-1]
                else:
                    # Numbering scheme is row-major
                    lower_cluster, upper_cluster = \
                        (clusters[i-1, j], clusters[i, j-1]) \
                        if (clusters[i-1, j] < clusters[i, j-1]) \
                        else (clusters[i, j-1], clusters[i-1, j])

                    clusters[i, j] = lower_cluster
                    clusters[clusters == upper_cluster
                            ] = lower_cluster
    return clusters


cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE=np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def optimized_fun(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] lattice, int default_val = -1):
    cdef int shape0 = lattice.shape[0]
    cdef int shape1 = lattice.shape[1]

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] ids = np.reshape(
        np.arange(
            1, shape0*shape1 + 1
        ),
        (shape0, shape1))

    cdef int i, j, jshift, ishift, x, y    
    cdef DTYPE_t left_occ, up_occ, lower_cluster, upper_cluster
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] clusters = default_val*np.ones_like(lattice, dtype = DTYPE)
    for i in range(shape0):
        for j in range(shape1):
            if lattice[i, j]:
                ishift = i-1
                jshift = j-1

                if i == 0:
                    left_occ = 0
                else:
                    left_occ = lattice[ishift, j]

                if j == 0:
                    up_occ = 0
                else:
                    up_occ = lattice[i, jshift]

                if not left_occ and not up_occ:
                    clusters[i, j] = ids[i, j]
                elif left_occ and not up_occ:
                    clusters[i, j] = clusters[ishift, j]
                elif not left_occ and up_occ:
                    clusters[i, j] = clusters[i, jshift]
                else:
                  if (clusters[ishift, j] < clusters[i, jshift]):
                        lower_cluster = clusters[ishift, j]
                        upper_cluster = clusters[i, jshift]
                    else:
                        lower_cluster = clusters[i, jshift]
                        upper_cluster = clusters[ishift, j]

                    clusters[i, j] = lower_cluster
                    #clusters[clusters == upper_cluster
                        #] = lower_cluster
                    # Note that the above line using numpy logic performs substantially faster than the below loop. However, the types of upper_cluster, lower_cluster, and the clusters array all seem to match appropriately. 
                    for x in range(shape0):
                        for y in range(shape1):
                            if clusters[x, y] == upper_cluster:
                                clusters[x, y] = lower_cluster

    return clusters
```

### Setup script

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Compiler import Options
import numpy as np

directive_defaults = Options.get_directive_defaults()

directive_defaults['linetrace'] = True
directive_defaults['binding'] = True


extensions = [
    Extension("cython_fail.test_extension", ["cython_fail/test_extension.pyx"], define_macros=[('CYTHON_TRACE', '1')])
]

includes = [
    np.get_include()
]


setup(name = 'cython_fail',
        packages = ['cython_fail'],
        include_dirs = includes,
        ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```

### Profiling code

```
# filename: profiling.py

import cython_fail
import numpy as np

N = 100
p = 0.58
lattice = (np.random.rand(N, N) < p).astype(np.int)

#import line_profiler

#profile = line_profiler.LineProfiler(cython_fail.test_extension.fun)
#profile.runcall(cython_fail.test_extension.fun, lattice)
#profile.print_stats()
##
#profile = line_profiler.LineProfiler(cython_fail.test_extension.optimized_fun)
#profile.runcall(cython_fail.test_extension.optimized_fun, lattice)
#profile.print_stats()
#quit()
#
#
#
import timeit
original = timeit.timeit("cython_fail.test_extension.fun(lattice)",
            setup="import cython_fail; from __main__ import lattice",
            number=100)
optimized = timeit.timeit("cython_fail.test_extension.optimized_fun(lattice)",
            setup="import cython_fail; from __main__ import lattice",
            number=100)
print("Time to run normally: {}\nTime to run optimized: {}".format(original, optimized))
```

I've included code for line profiling as well if that is helpful to anyone using the [Line Profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) module. For reference, the output of the simple timeit runs above is:

```
Time to run normally:  3.9105381628032774
Time to run optimized: 9.10740948910825
```

### Update

I've moved the profiling.py script into the root (it is not `cython_test/test_package/profiling.py` instead of just `cython_test/profiling.py`, and I am now using this simple bash script to run the tests

```
# run_tests.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f ]; then
    rm -rf build
fi
if [ -f cython_fail/test_extension.c ]; then
    rm cython_fail/test_extension.c
fi
if [ -f cython_fail/test_extension.cpython-34m.so ]; then
    rm test_extension.cpython-34m.so
fi
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
python3 profiling.py
```

### Update 2

I've established that the problem does not persist if I switch architectures from a Linux box to Mac. The result of running line-by-line profiling on the Linux box is below.

```
Total time: 9.66717 s
File: cython_fail/test_extension.pyx
Function: optimized_fun at line 47

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    47                                           def optimized_fun(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] lattice, int default_val = -1):
    48         1            3      3.0      0.0      cdef int shape0 = lattice.shape[0]
    49         1            1      1.0      0.0      cdef int shape1 = lattice.shape[1]
    50
    51         2            5      2.5      0.0      cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] ids = np.reshape(
    52         1            1      1.0      0.0          np.arange(
    53         1           51     51.0      0.0              1, shape0*shape1 + 1
    54                                                   ),
    55         1           25     25.0      0.0          (shape0, shape1))
    56
    57                                               cdef int i, j, jshift, ishift, x, y
    58                                               cdef DTYPE_t left_occ, up_occ, lower_cluster, upper_cluster
    59         1          143    143.0      0.0      cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] clusters = default_val*np.ones_like(lattice, dtype = DTYPE)
    60         1            6      6.0      0.0      for i in range(shape0):
    61       100           48      0.5      0.0          for j in range(shape1):
    62     10000         5129      0.5      0.1              if lattice[i, j]:
    63      5818         2718      0.5      0.0                  ishift = i-1
    64      5818         2728      0.5      0.0                  jshift = j-1
    65
    66      5818         2765      0.5      0.0                  if i == 0:
    67        57           28      0.5      0.0                      left_occ = 0
    68                                                           else:
    69      5761         2789      0.5      0.0                      left_occ = lattice[ishift, j]
    70
    71      5818         2762      0.5      0.0                  if j == 0:
    72        60           24      0.4      0.0                      up_occ = 0
    73                                                           else:
    74      5758         2689      0.5      0.0                      up_occ = lattice[i, jshift]
    75
    76      5818         2788      0.5      0.0                  if not left_occ and not up_occ:
    77      1032          582      0.6      0.0                      clusters[i, j] = ids[i, j]
    78      4786         2287      0.5      0.0                  elif left_occ and not up_occ:
    79      1431          692      0.5      0.0                      clusters[i, j] = clusters[ishift, j]
    80      3355         1607      0.5      0.0                  elif not left_occ and up_occ:
    81      1397          674      0.5      0.0                      clusters[i, j] = clusters[i, jshift]
    82                                                           else:
    83
    84      1958          933      0.5      0.0                      if (clusters[ishift, j] < clusters[i, jshift]):
    85       526          236      0.4      0.0                          lower_cluster = clusters[ishift, j]
    86       526          259      0.5      0.0                          upper_cluster = clusters[i, jshift]
    87                                                               else:
    88      1432          688      0.5      0.0                          lower_cluster = clusters[i, jshift]
    89      1432          685      0.5      0.0                          upper_cluster = clusters[ishift, j]
    90
    91      1958          937      0.5      0.0                      clusters[i, j] = lower_cluster
    92                                                               #clusters[clusters == upper_cluster
    93                                                                       #] = lower_cluster
    94      1958          948      0.5      0.0                      for x in range(shape0):
    95    195800        91754      0.5      0.9                          for y in range(shape1):
    96  19580000      9274425      0.5     95.9                              if clusters[x, y] == upper_cluster:
    97    528427       265750      0.5      2.7                                  clusters[x, y] = lower_cluster
    98
    99         1            8      8.0      0.0      return clusters
```

### Update 3

This is the diff of the actual C files generated. A couple notes:

1. I've tried both upgrading and downgrading cython versions on both systems to match, and still received the same results.
2. Various obviously meaningless lines were removed before posting.
3. There are some lines to do with fastcalls or functions with keywords that look suspicious, but I don't know nearly enough about cython or its naming conventions to know what those mean in the code it generates.

The < lines are the slower version, and the > lines correspond to the faster code.

```
1c1
< /* Generated by Cython 0.26.1 */
---
> /* Generated by Cython 0.25.2 */
12,19c12
<         "depends": [],
<         "extra_compile_args": [
<             "-g"
<         ],
<         "name": "cython_fail.test_extension",
<         "sources": [
<             "cython_fail/test_extension.pyx"
<         ]
---
>         "depends": []
32c25
< #define CYTHON_ABI "0_26_1"
---
> #define CYTHON_ABI "0_25_2"
54d46
< #define __PYX_COMMA ,
72,73d63
<   #undef CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP
<   #define CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP 0
101,102d90
<   #undef CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP
<   #define CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP 0
134,139d121
<   #if PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x02070000
<     #undef CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP
<     #define CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP 0
<   #elif !defined(CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP)
<     #define CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP 1
<   #endif
217,223c199,202
< #if PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x030700A0 || !defined(METH_FASTCALL)
<   #ifndef METH_FASTCALL
<      #define METH_FASTCALL 0x80
<   #endif
<   typedef PyObject *(*__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast) (PyObject *self, PyObject **args, Py_ssize_t nargs);
<   typedef PyObject *(*__Pyx_PyCFunctionFastWithKeywords) (PyObject *self, PyObject **args,
<                                                           Py_ssize_t nargs, PyObject *kwnames);
---
> #ifndef METH_FASTCALL
>   #define METH_FASTCALL 0x80
>   typedef PyObject *(*__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast) (PyObject *self, PyObject **args,
>                                               Py_ssize_t nargs, PyObject *kwnames);
226d204
<   #define __Pyx_PyCFunctionFastWithKeywords _PyCFunctionFastWithKeywords
230c208
<     ((PyCFunction_Check(func) && (METH_FASTCALL == (PyCFunction_GET_FLAGS(func) & ~(METH_CLASS | METH_STATIC | METH_COEXIST | METH_KEYWORDS)))))
---
>     ((PyCFunction_Check(func) && (METH_FASTCALL == (PyCFunction_GET_FLAGS(func) & ~(METH_CLASS | METH_STATIC | METH_COEXIST)))))
357,362d334
< #ifndef __has_attribute
<   #define __has_attribute(x) 0
< #endif
< #ifndef __has_cpp_attribute
<   #define __has_cpp_attribute(x) 0
< #endif
417,445d388
< #ifdef _MSC_VER
<     #ifndef _MSC_STDINT_H_
<         #if _MSC_VER < 1300
<            typedef unsigned char     uint8_t;
<            typedef unsigned int      uint32_t;
<         #else
<            typedef unsigned __int8   uint8_t;
<            typedef unsigned __int32  uint32_t;
<         #endif
<     #endif
< #else
<    #include <stdint.h>
< #endif
< #ifndef CYTHON_FALLTHROUGH
<   #ifdef __cplusplus
<     #if __has_cpp_attribute(fallthrough)
<       #define CYTHON_FALLTHROUGH [[fallthrough]]
<     #elif __has_cpp_attribute(clang::fallthrough)
<       #define CYTHON_FALLTHROUGH [[clang::fallthrough]]
<     #endif
<   #endif
<   #ifndef CYTHON_FALLTHROUGH
<     #if __has_attribute(fallthrough) || (defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__attribute__))
<       #define CYTHON_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__((fallthrough))
<     #else
<       #define CYTHON_FALLTHROUGH
<     #endif
<   #endif
< #endif
553,554c496,497
< static CYTHON_INLINE const char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(PyObject*);
< static CYTHON_INLINE const char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsStringAndSize(PyObject*, Py_ssize_t* length);
---
> static CYTHON_INLINE char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(PyObject*);
> static CYTHON_INLINE char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsStringAndSize(PyObject*, Py_ssize_t* length);
567,571c510,511
< #define __Pyx_PyObject_AsWritableString(s)    ((char*) __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(s))
< #define __Pyx_PyObject_AsWritableSString(s)    ((signed char*) __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(s))
< #define __Pyx_PyObject_AsWritableUString(s)    ((unsigned char*) __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(s))
< #define __Pyx_PyObject_AsSString(s)    ((const signed char*) __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(s))
< #define __Pyx_PyObject_AsUString(s)    ((const unsigned char*) __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(s))
---
> #define __Pyx_PyObject_AsSString(s)    ((signed char*) __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(s))
> #define __Pyx_PyObject_AsUString(s)    ((unsigned char*) __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(s))
693d632
< static CYTHON_INLINE void __Pyx_pretend_to_initialize(void* ptr) { (void)ptr; }
698d636
< static PyObject *__pyx_cython_runtime;
1268c1206
<   #define __Pyx_TraceCall(funcname, srcfile, firstlineno, nogil, goto_error)   if ((1)); else goto_error;
---
>   #define __Pyx_TraceCall(funcname, srcfile, firstlineno, nogil, goto_error)   if (1); else goto_error;
1326c1264
<   #define __Pyx_TraceLine(lineno, nogil, goto_error)   if ((1)); else goto_error;
---
>   #define __Pyx_TraceLine(lineno, nogil, goto_error)   if (1); else goto_error;
1451,1453d1388
< /* IsLittleEndian.proto */
< static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_Is_Little_Endian(void);
< 
1461c1396
<                               __Pyx_TypeInfo* type);
---
>                               __Pyx_TypeInfo* type); // PROTO
1580,1582d1514
< /* CLineInTraceback.proto */
< static int __Pyx_CLineForTraceback(int c_line);
< 
1845d1776
< static const char __pyx_k_cline_in_traceback[] = "cline_in_traceback";
1848c1779
< static const char __pyx_k_cython_fail_test_extension_pyx[] = "cython_fail/test_extension.pyx";
---
1867d1798
< static PyObject *__pyx_n_s_cline_in_traceback;
1870d1800
< static PyObject *__pyx_kp_s_cython_fail_test_extension_pyx;
6778d6697
<   {&__pyx_n_s_cline_in_traceback, __pyx_k_cline_in_traceback, sizeof(__pyx_k_cline_in_traceback), 0, 0, 1, 1},
6781d6699
<   {&__pyx_kp_s_cython_fail_test_extension_pyx, __pyx_k_cython_fail_test_extension_pyx, sizeof(__pyx_k_cython_fail_test_extension_pyx), 0, 0, 1, 0},
6951c6869
<   __pyx_codeobj_ = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 11, 0, 0, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__13, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_cython_fail_test_extension_pyx, __pyx_n_s_fun, 4, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj_)) __PYX_ERR(0, 4, __pyx_L1_error)
---
6966c6884
<   __pyx_codeobj__3 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 16, 0, 0, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__15, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_cython_fail_test_extension_pyx, __pyx_n_s_optimized_fun, 47, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 47, __pyx_L1_error)
---
7042d6959
<   __pyx_cython_runtime = PyImport_AddModule((char *) "cython_runtime"); if (unlikely(!__pyx_cython_runtime)) __PYX_ERR(0, 1, __pyx_L1_error)
7167c7084
---
7184c7101
<       __Pyx_AddTraceback("init cython_fail.test_extension", 0, __pyx_lineno, __pyx_filename);
---
>       __Pyx_AddTraceback("init cython_fail.test_extension", __pyx_clineno, __pyx_lineno, __pyx_filename);
7686,7687c7603,7604
< #endif
< #endif
---
> #endif  // CPython < 3.6
> #endif  // CYTHON_FAST_PYCALL
7695d7611
<     int flags = PyCFunction_GET_FLAGS(func);
7697c7613
<     assert(METH_FASTCALL == (flags & ~(METH_CLASS | METH_STATIC | METH_COEXIST | METH_KEYWORDS)));
---
>     assert(METH_FASTCALL == (PyCFunction_GET_FLAGS(func) & ~(METH_CLASS | METH_STATIC | METH_COEXIST)));
7704,7708c7620
<     if ((PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x030700A0) || unlikely(flags & METH_KEYWORDS)) {
<         return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFastWithKeywords)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
<     } else {
<         return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs);
<     }
---
>     return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
7710c7622
< #endif
---
> #endif  // CYTHON_FAST_PYCCALL
7769a7682,7684
> #ifdef __Pyx_CyFunction_USED
>     if (likely(PyCFunction_Check(func) || PyObject_TypeCheck(func, __pyx_CyFunctionType))) {
> #else
7770a7686
> #endif
8096c8012
<     static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__Pyx_GetItemInt_Generic(PyObject *o, PyObject* j) {
---
>       static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__Pyx_GetItemInt_Generic(PyObject *o, PyObject* j) {
8107,8112c8023,8025
<     Py_ssize_t wrapped_i = i;
<     if (wraparound & unlikely(i < 0)) {
<         wrapped_i += PyList_GET_SIZE(o);
<     }
<     if ((!boundscheck) || likely((0 <= wrapped_i) & (wrapped_i < PyList_GET_SIZE(o)))) {
<         PyObject *r = PyList_GET_ITEM(o, wrapped_i);
---
>     if (wraparound & unlikely(i < 0)) i += PyList_GET_SIZE(o);
>     if ((!boundscheck) || likely((0 <= i) & (i < PyList_GET_SIZE(o)))) {
>         PyObject *r = PyList_GET_ITEM(o, i);
8125,8130c8038,8040
<     Py_ssize_t wrapped_i = i;
<     if (wraparound & unlikely(i < 0)) {
<         wrapped_i += PyTuple_GET_SIZE(o);
<     }
<     if ((!boundscheck) || likely((0 <= wrapped_i) & (wrapped_i < PyTuple_GET_SIZE(o)))) {
<         PyObject *r = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(o, wrapped_i);
---
>     if (wraparound & unlikely(i < 0)) i += PyTuple_GET_SIZE(o);
>     if ((!boundscheck) || likely((0 <= i) & (i < PyTuple_GET_SIZE(o)))) {
>         PyObject *r = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(o, i);
8343,8353d8252
< /* IsLittleEndian */
<     static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_Is_Little_Endian(void)
< {
<   union {
<     uint32_t u32;
<     uint8_t u8[4];
<   } S;
<   S.u32 = 0x01020304;
<   return S.u8[0] == 4;
< }
< 
8355c8254,8258
<     static void __Pyx_BufFmt_Init(__Pyx_BufFmt_Context* ctx,
---
>       static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_IsLittleEndian(void) {
>   unsigned int n = 1;
>   return *(unsigned char*)(&n) != 0;
> }
> static void __Pyx_BufFmt_Init(__Pyx_BufFmt_Context* ctx,
8741c8644
<         if (!__Pyx_Is_Little_Endian()) {
---
>         if (!__Pyx_IsLittleEndian()) {
8750c8653
<         if (__Pyx_Is_Little_Endian()) {
---
>         if (__Pyx_IsLittleEndian()) {
8901c8804
<       static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_TypeTest(PyObject *obj, PyTypeObject *type) {
---
>         static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_TypeTest(PyObject *obj, PyTypeObject *type) {
8914c8817
<       static void __Pyx_WriteUnraisable(const char *name, CYTHON_UNUSED int clineno,
---
>         static void __Pyx_WriteUnraisable(const char *name, CYTHON_UNUSED int clineno,
8956c8859
<       #if CYTHON_FAST_THREAD_STATE
---
>         #if CYTHON_FAST_THREAD_STATE
8980c8883
<       #if CYTHON_FAST_THREAD_STATE
---
>         #if CYTHON_FAST_THREAD_STATE
8990c8893
<       #if CYTHON_FAST_THREAD_STATE
---
>         #if CYTHON_FAST_THREAD_STATE
9051c8954
<         static PyObject *__Pyx_Import(PyObject *name, PyObject *from_list, int level) {
---
>           static PyObject *__Pyx_Import(PyObject *name, PyObject *from_list, int level) {
9125c9028
<         static PyTypeObject* __Pyx_FetchCommonType(PyTypeObject* type) {
---
>           static PyTypeObject* __Pyx_FetchCommonType(PyTypeObject* type) {
9164c9067
<         static PyObject *
---
>           static PyObject *
9746,9781d9648
< /* CLineInTraceback */
<             static int __Pyx_CLineForTraceback(int c_line) {
< #ifdef CYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK
<     return ((CYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK)) ? c_line : 0;
< #else
<     PyObject *use_cline;
< #if CYTHON_COMPILING_IN_CPYTHON
<     PyObject **cython_runtime_dict = _PyObject_GetDictPtr(__pyx_cython_runtime);
<     if (likely(cython_runtime_dict)) {
<       use_cline = PyDict_GetItem(*cython_runtime_dict, __pyx_n_s_cline_in_traceback);
<     } else
< #endif
<     {
<       PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
<       PyObject *use_cline_obj;
<       PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
<       use_cline_obj = __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr(__pyx_cython_runtime, __pyx_n_s_cline_in_traceback);
<       if (use_cline_obj) {
<         use_cline = PyObject_Not(use_cline_obj) ? Py_False : Py_True;
<         Py_DECREF(use_cline_obj);
<       } else {
<         use_cline = NULL;
<       }
<       PyErr_Restore(ptype, pvalue, ptraceback);
<     }
<     if (!use_cline) {
<         c_line = 0;
<         PyObject_SetAttr(__pyx_cython_runtime, __pyx_n_s_cline_in_traceback, Py_False);
<     }
<     else if (PyObject_Not(use_cline) != 0) {
<         c_line = 0;
<     }
<     return c_line;
< #endif
< }
< 
9922,9925c9789
<     if (c_line) {
<         c_line = __Pyx_CLineForTraceback(c_line);
<     }
<     py_code = __pyx_find_code_object(c_line ? -c_line : py_line);
---
>     py_code = __pyx_find_code_object(c_line ? c_line : py_line);
9930c9794
<         __pyx_insert_code_object(c_line ? -c_line : py_line, py_code);
---
>         __pyx_insert_code_object(c_line ? c_line : py_line, py_code);
9960,9962c9824
<     if ((0)) {}
<         else if (PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, __pyx_ptype_5numpy_ndarray)) __pyx_pw_5numpy_7ndarray_3__releasebuffer__(obj, view);
<     view->obj = NULL;
---
>         if (PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, __pyx_ptype_5numpy_ndarray)) { __pyx_pw_5numpy_7ndarray_3__releasebuffer__(obj, view); return; }
9963a9826
>     view->obj = NULL;
9968,9969c9831,9832
<             /* CIntFromPyVerify */
<             #define __PYX_VERIFY_RETURN_INT(target_type, func_type, func_value)\
---
>               /* CIntFromPyVerify */
>               #define __PYX_VERIFY_RETURN_INT(target_type, func_type, func_value)\
10927,10928d10789
<         if (PyObject_Hash(*t->p) == -1)
<             PyErr_Clear();
10937c10798
< static CYTHON_INLINE const char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(PyObject* o) {
---
> static CYTHON_INLINE char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(PyObject* o) {
10941c10802
< static CYTHON_INLINE const char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsStringAndSize(PyObject* o, Py_ssize_t *length) {
---
> static CYTHON_INLINE char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsStringAndSize(PyObject* o, Py_ssize_t *length) {
```

Comment: That `0` in your final print statement in the profiling script caught me out for a moment - might want to fix that up

Comment: Whoops good call thanks. Remnants of my various attempts to figure out what was happening.

Comment: Also, after fixing that, your optimized version runs faster for me: `Time to run normally: 2.072774930999003
Time to run optimized: 1.546479910997732`

Comment: Hmm I can't reproduce that. How are you running? I'm doing a `python setup.py install --user` and then `python profiling.py`.

Comment: I ran `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` to build the module, then `python3 profiling.py` to run

Comment: I get very similar results to @lxop (once I've fixed a small indentation error in the Cython script). It might be worth triple-checking where the module is actually being imported from - i.e. are you 100% sure that you're importing the recompiled version and not one you did earlier

Comment: In particular, find where it is importing `cython_fail` from and delete it from there, then try my build line, which won't install it anywhere but just leave it in the source tree

Comment: And it occurs to me that you are calling `install` as opposed to `build` or `build_ext` - maybe you are not actually rebuilding the module?

Comment: @Ixop @DavidW I've switched to just building in place as you have (see newly included script above), and I've checked where it's importing from; it is now using the current directory. I'm still receiving comparable results to before, though: `Time to run normally: 3.7401027530431747
Time to run optimized: 9.397141619119793`

Comment: If you haven't already done so, print `test_extension.__file__` as extra confirmation that it's doing what you think. I'm not sure I can suggest much more given that it seems to work OK to me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: Linux, python3.6.2, cython 0.27.1, gcc-5.4: normally 7s, cython: 3.5s. The same for clang-3.8.

Comment: This appears to be an environment specific issue; I was running on a Linux workstation, but when I copied my code onto a Mac and ran it I received benchmarks much more similar to what everyone here appears to have attained `Time to run normally: 3.547995834145695
Time to run optimized: 1.6577479168772697`. Any thoughts on what could cause this? Specific compiler, gcc, etc issues?

Comment: Maybe post your compiler/python/cython versions and cpu?

Comment: I'm currently running Python 3.4.5 with Cython version 0.26.1. Originally was using gcc (output of `gcc --version`: `gcc (Gentoo 5.4.0-r3 p1.4, pie-0.6.5) 5.4.0`). Also tried using clang (output of `clang --version`: `clang version 3.8.1 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)` by explicitly setting the following in my setup.py script: `import os; os.environ["CC"] = "clang"; os.environ["CXX"] = "clang"`. For CPU, the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name'` is `model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz.

Comment: Does the produced C-code look different for Linux and Mac? What happens if you make N smaller or larger?

Comment: @ead The code is different, but it's not immediately obvious to me whether the differences are meaningful. I've updated the post above to include the full diff of C files, with lines that were obviously meaningless (e.g. with different indentation) redacted.

Comment: The produced C code has comments, so you can see the corresponding cython part. You need only to look for the line with 95% running time. But from your diff this part seems to be identical... same compile flags used?

Comment: Ah good point. Yes I checked those lines explicitly, and they are exactly identical down to variable naming. And yes same compile flags. FWIW I've rewritten my algorithm in a way that avoids this issue completely, but the new version is too different to shed any light on why the version posted here is so slow.

Comment: The diff between produced C files would be more useful if you used the same version of Cython on both machines - the diff you posted will be polluted with subtle changes to Cython's code generation between versions that have no effect on your problem (according to your findings). One thing I did see though, was the extra `-g` compiler flag added to the slow version.